# tensorflow test includes extra characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I just installed gpu based tensorflow, [(from these instructions)](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#ValidateYourInstallation) and ran the test code, but, I am confussed by the output. Where I think it should say: "Hello, Tensorflow"
it says "b'Hello Tensorflow".

what does it mean? why is there the extra characters?

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Comment: it is a [bytes-literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: I have a question for you: why are you testing it in this way? TensorFlow is for numerical computation. Anyway, follow the link reported by @SmartManoj.

Comment: I am following the aforementioned instructions